# how to recover contents from home folder if ubuntu fails to boot and requires reinstallation?

Tags: system-installation, backup, data-recovery, home-directory

i installed my IDE and have project on default home folder now in case ubuntu fails to boot how shall i recover contents from home folder. if make live USB ubuntu then it shows fresh home folder and doesn't show previous contents and if i reinstall it my previous contents might be deleted.What other option i have other than shifting my contents to other partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can boot from a Live CD (Or USB Stick), mount the partition and access any files stored in it.
So, unless you format the partition, you won't lose any of your data in case Ubuntu fails to boot for any reason.

But, if you're planning on toying/learning about Ubuntu (Or Linux in general), you should run a Virtual Box or create a separate partition, to avoid damaging any important data you may have.

In any case, it is a good practice to often backup your data in an external drive, as (Albeit small) there is a chance any file system will fail.